# Json.Net gives an error when creating my custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a problem whereby I wish to generate a JSON field where the field name is known at runtime e.g.:

```
{ "known_at_run_time": ["test","test","test"] }
```

So I tried implementing it this way, yet whenever I run my unit test I get an error saying that that my custom JsonConverter cannot be created.  Here is my code:

TermFilter.cs

```
public enum ExecutionType { plain, fielddata, @bool, and, or }

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class TermFilter
{
    #region PROPERTIES
    private JsonTuple query;

    private ExecutionType execution;
    private string _execution;

    private bool _cache;
    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public TermFilter()
    {
        try
        {
            this.query = null;
            this.Execution = ExecutionType.plain;
            this.Cache = true;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public TermFilter(ExecutionType execution)
        : this()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Execution = execution;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public TermFilter(ExecutionType execution, bool cache)
        : this(execution)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Cache = cache;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public TermFilter(string field, string[] terms)
        :this()
    {
        try
        {
            this.Query = new JsonTuple(field, new HashSet<string>(terms));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region GET/SET

    //[JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(JsonTupleConverter))]
    //[JsonProperty]
    [JsonConverter( typeof(JsonTupleConverter) )]
    public JsonTuple Query
    {
        get { return query; }
        set { query = value; }
    }

    public ExecutionType Execution
    {
        get { return execution; }
        set 
        { 
            execution = value;
            _execution = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "execution")]
    public string _Execution
    {
        get { return _execution; }
        set { _execution = value; }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_cache")]
    public bool Cache
    {
        get { return _cache; }
        set { _cache = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    public TermFilter AddTerm(string term)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.query.Data.Contains(term))
                this.query.Data.Add(term);

            return this;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        try
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
            settings.Converters.Add(new JsonTupleConverter(new Type[] { typeof(JsonTuple) }));
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings);

            //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new JsonTupleConverter(typeof(JsonTuple)));
            //return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new JsonConverter[] { new JsonTupleConverter(typeof(JsonTuple)),  });

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

JsonTuple.cs

```
public class JsonTuple
{
    #region PROPERTIES
    private string field;
    private HashSet<string> data;
    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTOR
    public JsonTuple()
    {
        try
        {
            this.field = null;
            this.data = null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public JsonTuple(string field, HashSet<string> data)
    {
        try
        {
            this.field = field;
            this.data = data;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region GET/SET
    public string Field
    {
        get { return field; }
        set { field = value; }
    }

    public HashSet<string> Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    public string ToJson()
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new JsonTupleConverter(typeof(JsonTuple)));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

JsonTupleConverter.cs

```
public class JsonTupleConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public JsonTupleConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        try
        {
            _types = types;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            JToken t = JToken.FromObject(value);

            if (t.Type != JTokenType.Object)
            {
                t.WriteTo(writer);
            }
            else if (!_types.Any(_t => _t == value.GetType()))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            }
            else
            {
                JsonTuple tuple = (JsonTuple)value;
                if ((tuple != null) && (tuple.Field != null) && (tuple.Data != null))
                {
                    JToken entityToken = null;
                    if (tuple.Data != null)
                        entityToken = JToken.FromObject(tuple.Data);

                    JObject o = new JObject();
                    o.AddFirst(new JProperty(tuple.Field, entityToken));
                    o.WriteTo(writer);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }
}
```

Test.cs

```
[TestMethod]
public void TermFieldSertialization()
{
    try
    {
        TermFilter filter = new TermFilter("test.field", new string[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"});
        Assert.IsNotNull(filter);

        string sampleJson = filter.ToJson();
        Assert.IsNotNull(sampleJson);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any information will help.

Comment: When posting code producing an error like this, it's best to reduce the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the error. Seeing a wall of code is going to make many potential answerers ignore your question.

Comment: Please pick a better question title. Just repeating tags and/or class name without any other information is generally considered not acceptable on SO. A question's title shall be a one-line *summary* of its contents — just like with email subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try removing the `[JsonConverter]` attribute from the `Query` property of your `TermFilter` class.  You don't need it because the `Query` property is a `JsonTuple`, and you are already passing an instance of your `JsonTupleConverter` to the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method inside your `ToJson()` method, specifying that it can handle `JsonTuples`.  This will get rid of the error.

However, there is still another issue.  It seems that your intent is to get the `Query` property to serialize to JSON, but as things stand now this will not happen.  This is because you have marked your `TermFilter` class with `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]`, and the `Query` property lacks a `[JsonProperty]` attribute to signal that you want that property to be included in the output.  You will need to add `[JsonProperty("query")]` to fix that.  Once you have done that, you should get the output you expect.

As an aside, you don't need to catch exceptions if you only intend to throw them again without doing anything else with them.  I see that pattern everywhere in your code.  Instead, just leave out the try/catch altogether; it does exactly the same thing and will make your code much more concise.  Only catch an exception if you intend to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your exception is occurring because `JsonTupleConverter` doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

```
public JsonTupleConverter() { }
```

If you add that, the error should go away, but your code might not work because then it'd probably be trying to use a converter without the types set up correctly.

Maybe you should just be serializing it as a dictionary? E.g.

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "known_at_run_time", new List<string> { "test","test","test" } }
};
string ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDict);
// ser is {"known_at_run_time":["test","test","test"]}
```